# How can I manually change an EXE's Window Title?

Tags: windows, window

I'm setting up a flash game collection on my server network and providing web-based versions of the games, along with `.exe`-based versions I made by compiling the `.fla` files.

How do I change the Window Title so it doesn't say `FLA Compiled Frame`, changing it to the game's name?

Answer (score 1):

[Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) is used to change the caption:

1. Open the `.exe` in Resource Hacker
2. Search [magnifying glass] for the first word of your window title, resulting with file `TFRMAIN` *(only flash executables do this, else whatever your process is called)*:

   - Inside it should show:

     ```
     Caption = 'Your Windows Current Caption'
     ```
3. Change the text by clicking on the end of the caption before the single quote 
    *(Do not use single quotes, or any other codebreaking characters, in the name)*
4. Compile by clicking on another portion of the `.exe`
5. Save the `.exe` and re-compile it [green floppy disk]
6. Rename original to `<name>_Original.exe` 
    *(a second `.exe` is created as a safeguard in case of corruption)*

Comment: Just an FYI _(may or may not apply to your use-case)_ since you've compiled the `*.exe`: once an `*.exe` has been modified, it corrupts any digital signature the executable had, which can be resolved by using [`signtool`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46713936/6819406) from the Windows SDK; however, while not applying to this specific use-case, if modifying an executable installed by an installer or a system executable, ensure a backup is maintained, as the executable would no longer have the expected hash or signature, being seen as corrupted by an installer or, if a system executable, `sfc`.

Comment: @JW0914 As I mentioned in my answer, Resource hacker automatically saves a copy of the original executable before compiling specifically for this issue....

Comment: I was referring to saving a backup of the modified executable, not the original, which doesn't apply to your use-case scenario but would to someone using this answer to modify an executable installed via an installer with a repair option or a Windows system file, as the repair functionality of an installer or `sfc` will replace a modified executable with the original since the modified executable would be seen as corrupt _(digital signature would be corrupted and the hash wouldn't match)_.

Comment: @JW0914 wouldn't that be pretty common sense to backup an executable? I mean most applications nowadays can be easily reinstalled without any consequences (Excusing applications that delete their own save data when you uninstall them)